# Reading package lists...Error!

Tags: apt

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/dpkg/status (1)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

What each line is saying and how to solve it?

I'm running Linux Mint 17 Qiana Cinnamon in VMWare Workstation 10.0.2.

Comment: Does `/var/lib/dpkg/status` exist? If so, what are its permissions, and is it empty? If not, what does it contain?

Comment: Yes, it does exist. Its permissions are 644. It contains a detailed list of packages-such as the package name, status, priority...etcetera. There is also a "status-old" file with the same permissions. It appears to contain the same information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you google out this error there are plenty of links which describe this error. It seems that the file is messed up. You can try out the options specified [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/410045/the-package-lists-or-status-file-could-not-be-parsed-or-opened).

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
```

**This below option did not work for this particular case.**

Another link that describes the similar issue is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2078996).

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: The first option worked. I tried the second option first, but the error appeared again. Thanks Ramesh.

Comment: Welcome to U & L Stack Exchange. Glad it worked. :)

Comment: @Ramesh that's mine. :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj, yeah. I see you are pretty active in AU than here :)

Comment: @Ramesh you must remove the second code block. Because removing the files inside `/var/lib/apt/lists/` shouldn't work for him.

Comment: I had the same problem and tried all the solutions I found without success. So I edited /var/lib/dpkg/status and cut off the block with last package. The package was python-sphinx. This worked for me.

Comment: The above didn't work for me. I also tried `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vfr` (to delete a subdir that remained) then had to reboot the server before it worked again.

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine to remove files in lists folder.

By the way `apt-get` is working fine after command line bash I found out over The Net.

Just add:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

to have an update/upgrade working at well.