# Reading package lists…Error!

Tags: debian, apt

I'm running an old Debian 3.1, and I'm trying to run "apt-get update" to no avail. I've read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139441/reading-package-lists-error) thread, but neither solution, or the comment section has helped. Going back to the old status file or removing the lists under `/var/lib/apt/lists/` gets me back to square one: the first time I run "apt-get update" it starts downloading stuff until eventually the error occurs, and all the subsequent times I try to run any apt-get command (update, install...) I will get the exact same error without all the previous downloading:

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Malformed provides line
E: An error occurred while processing libapt-inst2.0 (NewVersion1)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/ftp.us.debian.org_debian_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I've read other threads from different forums, which usually suggest removing not all the lists, but just the one causing the problem, or cutting out the package libapt-inst2.0 from the the status file, but there's definitely no such string ("libapt-inst2.0") in /var/lib/dpkg/status - I just need to be able to use apt-get somehow, and it didn't even work before updating. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: If you are really running 3.1, you might want to upgrade to something more recent and actually supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sources.list` (the list of package repositories) refers to `stable`, which is now Debian 9 (and hasn’t been Debian 3.1 for ten years) — that error saved your system from a rather messy mix-up if you ever tried upgrading or installing a package!

To fix this, you need to replace `stable` with `sarge` (the code name for Debian 3.1):

```
sed -i s/stable/sarge/g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You’ll also need to use an archive containing the older releases; in your case, `ftp.us.debian.org` would be appropriate:

```
sed -i sXftp.us.debian.orgXftp.us.debian.org/debian-archiveXg /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then `apt-get update` should work fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your help. I've backed up my sources.list file, which contained this:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stable main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stable main

deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ stable main
deb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ stable main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib
```

And then, of course, after running sed it's like this:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ sarge main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ sarge main

deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ sarge main
deb-src http://mirrors.kernel.org/debian/ sarge main

deb http://security.debian.org/ sarge/updates main contrib
```

However, this is causing trillions of errors everywhere when trying to run apt-get update :( I don't see the point of copying such a long stream of errors here. Any idea how I can fix my sources file for my version of Debian, or where I can read and learn about it? Thanks a million!!!